# BrowserRouter causing Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am getting the following error when using **react-router-dom version 6**:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

It is saying my **BrowserRouter** is the problem which seems to point to a mismatch of React and the renderer. However, I can't find any issues. Below is the piece of code that is causing the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={Home}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Doing a **npm ls react** yields the below:

```
├─┬ react-bootstrap@2.0.4
│ ├─┬ @restart/hooks@0.4.5
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @restart/ui@0.2.5
│ │ ├─┬ @react-aria/ssr@3.1.0
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ prop-types-extra@1.1.1
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├── react@17.0.2
│ └─┬ uncontrollable@7.2.1
│   └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.2.1 extraneous
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
└─┬ react-router@6.2.1 extraneous
  └── react@17.0.2 deduped
```

I'm blocked by this and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Post the code for your `<Home />` component. Also the element should actually be an element so `<Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />

Answer (score 26):

I found the issue! I have two package.json files - one in my react app and one outside of it. I had my react-router-dom installed in the wrong package.json. Installing it in the react-app itself fixed the problem.

Comment: So glad I found this post. I was about to pull my hair out trying to figure this out lol. I did the same thing. Installed  react-router in the wrong folder lmao.

Comment: Yrp. thanks for sharing. Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same code and was facing similar issue, I followed the below dirty fix.

1. Go to package.json file and add line `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",` (current as of 2022) right below `"react-router": "^6.x.x",`.
2. Go to project directory and use `rm -rf node-modules/*` to remove all node modules (We will install all modules in next step).
3. Use `npm install` to install node-modules and `npm start` to run react app in browser. You may also try in Incognito mode if error still comes.

Hopefully, this worked for me. Hope it helps!