# Why is my React App not showing react functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm on localhost:3000 and I'm getting an empty page. I'm using a tutorial, but its 2 years old and I've already had an issue with a part of it being outdated, so the terminology had changed since (not sure if that's what's causing my problem).

This is my App() to run it on port 3000:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/home.js";
import About from "./components/about.js";
import Contact from "./components/contact.js";
import Exhibitions from "./components/exhibitions.js";
import SelectedSet from "./components/set.js";
import EachCategory from "./components/selectedCategory.js";
import Gallery from "./components/gallery.js";
import Commissions from "./components/commissions.js";
import ShopItem from "./components//shop-item.js";
import Shop from "./components/shop.js";
import Help from "./components/help.js";
import Cart from "./components/cart.js";

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route component={Home} path='/' exact/>
                <Route component={About} path='/about' />
                <Route component={Contact} path='/contact' />
                <Route component={Exhibitions} path='/exhibitions' />
                <Route component={SelectedSet} path='/gallery/:slug/:slug' />
                <Route component={EachCategory} path='/gallery:slug' />
                <Route component={Gallery} path='/gallery' />
                <Route component={Commissions} path='/commissions' />
                <Route component={ShopItem} path='/shop/:slug' />
                <Route component={Shop} path='/shop' />
                <Route component={Help} path='/help' />
                <Route component={Cart} path='/cart' />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App;
```

and at the moment, I just want to test out that I can see anything on the page (which I currently cannot, though they are connected). This is the home:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Home(){
    return (
    <h1>home page!</h1>
    )
}
```

In the console, it says things like:

- react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
- The above error occurred in the  component:
  at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1790:5)
  at App

I don't really get what's going on.

Edit: just in case, i've tried with both home.js and home-page.jsx

Comment: There not enough data to understand problem. Better to show at least folder structure and package.json versions of  intalled packages.

Btw, try to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474837/browserrouter-causing-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the

Maybe you have same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383919/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-useref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see here is that the `Route` components are not rendering their content on the `element` prop. `react-router-dom@6` removed the `component` (*and `render` and `children` function props*) and replaced them with a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. Without using the correct props there's nothing to render onto the screen.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Home />} path='/' />
    <Route element={<About />} path='/about' />
    <Route element={<Contact />} path='/contact' />
    <Route element={<Exhibitions />} path='/exhibitions' />
    <Route element={<SelectedSet />} path='/gallery/:slug/:slug' />
    <Route element={<EachCategory />} path='/gallery:slug' />
    <Route element={<Gallery />} path='/gallery' />
    <Route element={<Commissions />} path='/commissions' />
    <Route element={<ShopItem />} path='/shop/:slug' />
    <Route element={<Shop />} path='/shop' />
    <Route element={<Help />} path='/help' />
    <Route element={<Cart />} path='/cart' />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```